# Is the following proof of trigonometric sums correct?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

When differentiating $\sin\theta$ using the $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ definition of a derivative instead of geometric techniques, the following formula needs to be known:

> $$\sin P-\sin Q=2\cos(\frac{P+Q}{2})\sin(\frac{P-Q}{2})$$

here is it's proof:

$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta)=(\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta))-(\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta))$$ $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta)=2\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

from here, let $\theta=\alpha+\beta$ and $\phi=\alpha-\beta$,

hence, it can be calculated that 
$$\beta=\alpha-\phi$$ hence $$\theta=2\alpha-\phi$$
$$\mathcal{\displaystyle\alpha=\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}}$$
 and that
 $$\alpha=\phi+\beta$$ 
hence 
$$\theta=\phi+2\beta$$
$$\mathcal {\beta=\displaystyle\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}}$$
 therefore when substituting back into the equation:

> $$\sin(\theta)-\sin(\phi)=2\cos(\displaystyle\frac{\theta+\phi}{2})\sin(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2})$$

my only question is whether or not this proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's basically how you prove the sum-to-product formulas. How you solve the system $$\begin{cases}\alpha+\beta=P\\\alpha-\beta=Q\end{cases}$$ is largely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is right.
But it is not necessary that you need that formula,

> Alternate proof :
>   $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin (x+h)-\sin x}{h}$$
>   $$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h - \sin x}{h}$$
>   $$\text{As }h\to 0\text{  thus} \cos h \to 1$$
>   $$\text{.:} \cos h= 1$$
>   $$=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin x - \sin x + \cos x \sin h}{h}$$
>   $$=\cos x \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$$
>   $$=\cos x$$

Comment: it's $\sin(h)$ that tends to zero with h tending to zero not the cosin function.  $\text{As }h\to 0\text{  thus} \cos h \to 1$

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that :)

Comment: You welcome... dosent change much in your proof

Comment: I actually like this proof more than the one I've been taught prior!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to consider this

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0} f(h) &=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin (x+h)-\sin x}{h} \\
\lim_{h\to 0} f(h) &=\lim_{h\to 0} 2\frac{\sin (\frac h 2)cos(x+ \frac h 2)}{h}
\end{align}

Since the limite is $\frac 0 0$ we apply L'hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=\lim_{h\to 0}  ({\cos(h/2)cos(x+h/2)-sin(h/2)sin(x+h/2)})$$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=\cos(x)$$